# What does the name after the closing class bracket means?

Tags: c++

I've encountered [this](http://ideone.com/gX5wF) code example and I remembered I've seen it before and I didn't know what it is for and what it does? I've searched on the internet but without luck.

Code:

```
class C
{
    int x; // a non-static variable, implicitly private

public:
    C() : x(0) {} // default constructor

    // a static member function, which uses a non-static variable perfectly well
    static int Incr(C& instance) { return ++(instance.x); }
} g_c;

int main(void)
{
    C c2;
    return C::Incr(g_c) + C::Incr(c2);
}
```

What does `g_c` after the last class bracket means?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
} g_c;
```

Here `g_c` is declared to be an object of the class type `C`.

Such construct enables you to create object(s) of unnamed type as:

```
class  //Nameless class!
{
   //data members

}obj1, obj2;
```

In this example, `obj1` and `obj2` are declared to be objects of a class type which has not been given any name — the class is *nameless*! In such situation, you cannot declare objects in a conventional sense (i.e `Type obj1, obj2;` sense). So this construct helps you do that.

You can even derive from other *named* classes while being *nameless* (and declaring the objects of the nameless class):

```
class : public A, public B //Nameless class is deriving from A and B
{
   //data members

}obj1, obj2;
```

In short, this construct ensures that the user wouldn't be able to create *more* objects than intended, unless some evil programmer uses/misuses/abuses C++11 (or template) as:

```
decltype(obj1) obj3; //hehe!
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the extra knowledge. I didn't know you can do that.

Answer (score 15):

It's shorthand for:

```
class C
{
    ....
};

C g_c;
```

Comment: So it's like instantiating the class into g_c right after the defining it and g_c is just like any normal class instance?

Answer (score 3):

You declare variables using the format `type variable_name;`.  For example:

```
A x;
```

Where A may be the name of a class.

But instead of using a pre-existing class type, you can also define the class at the same time as you declare a variable of the new class's type:

```
class { ... } x;
```

or define the class and give it a name:

```
class A { ... } x;
```

In C++ it is common to just define the class and give it a name, but leave off the variable:

```
class A { ... };
```

but you don't have to leave off the variable.

Comment: When reading, the word "it" is confusing. I think it means the variable in this one

Answer (score 1):

That's just a way of creating objects of that type of Class. Structs mostly use them to initialize new variables.